# Populating TableView Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

New to Swift, poking around and learning. I cannot seem to load anything into my TableView :/ I have followed several different walkthroughs (including Apple's) and trolled SO looking for solutions, but I must be overlooking something..

I was originally trying to pull data from a plist, then I gave up and tried with an array, then I gave up and tried to hardcode a string in, nothing!

- I tried with the default cell class first
- I've updated the custom class for the controller and the cell class I made.
- I tried adding the delegate/datasource = self in viewDidLoad()
- No breakpoints hit in the viewDidLoad() function, that seems weird to me.

TIA

```
class MessagesViewController: UITableViewController {

    let CellIdentifier = "MatchTableViewCell"

    var matches = [String]()
    var test = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        test = ["Pizza", "bungholio", "Metallica"]
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        tableView!.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)

        let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Books", ofType: "plist")

        let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
        matches = dict!.objectForKey("Matches") as! [String]


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3 //test.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Dequeue Resuable Cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MatchTableViewCell

        cell.nameLabel.text = "test" //test[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

EDIT: started a new project following this link, still no idea what went wrong after completing one successfully

https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/

Comment: Is your view controller the right class and type of object in IB?

Comment: @Ike10, the controller in IB is set to the MessagesViewController above, but I'm not sure where I would set/check the type of object in IB, can you elaborate?

Comment: When you dragged the object from the "object library" on the bottom right of the IB interface, was it a "Table View Controller" or "View Controller". If it was "View Controller" make sure there is an `@IBOutlet` for the `tableView` in `MessagesViewController`.

Comment: oh okay, it was a TableViewController

Comment: Make sure that you have an "Initial View Controller" set, the prototype cell has a cell identifier, and if using an external nib file make sure to use `registerNib` instead of register class.

Comment: My Initial View Controller is for the Tab Controller that the tableview lives within, the cell Identifier is set too! I'm not using a nib file unless that is the default setup. 

I'm still at a loss :/

Comment: can you plz add an output image so we can see the result even thought its empty

Comment: if there is no external nib for cell then you don't need to register it, remove tableView!.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)